# Copy from Active not Avialable for RB Constraints

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I forgot to set the rigid body constraints for a long chain to "hinge" and I want to copy the rigid body constraints from one empty to all the others. However Rigid Body > Copy from Active is greyed out...I can't perform the operation.

Does anyone know of a way to copy rigid body constraints to multiple empties?

[image]

Comment: why don't you just delete the empties, select all rigid bodies and then object -> rigid body connect -> and then choose these settings here: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/49eZ9.png (chain by distance is important)

Comment: Did not know about that (thanks), but it doesn't work in any case, because the hinge is dependent on the Z axis. If you do that for a chain, then the chain links will pas through each other. To do it properly, you need align the Z axis with where the chain link will pivot. Once you have 2 links, then you can duplicate the chain and use shift-R to copy and all the constraints will link together properly. In the end, rather than being able to copy the settings to the constraints I just had to start again.

Comment: normally you should be able to select all links and rotate them all at once in the direction you need